# .htaccess rewrite troubles with /index.php

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a small site with about 10 pages.

So I have made it so that the URL structure is rewritten via .htaccess simply: `www.domain.com/name.php` becomes `www.domain.com/name`

The trouble now is that I added some more pages and folder and want it to recognise: `www.domain.com/foldername/`

However it just cannot manage it. It gives me a 404 page not found as it is searching for `www.domain.com/foldername/.php`

My .htaccess code is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} . 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com\
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rule check for existence of corresponding `.php` file before adding `.php` extension:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava, thank you for your advice / help. It is really appreciated.